# How to make shorten URL like bit.ly

Tags: php, algorithm, url

I want to make a script to shorten URLs that works like Bit.ly.

If a Bit.ly shortened URL is, for example, `bit.ly/12Rgy3`, then how do I generate the `12Rgy3` part?

I want to store this information in a database, and I want to keep the length of those random strings between 3 and 6 characters only. How do I generate these strings so that I never get duplicates? I am using PHP.

Comment: You just want to split the string on '/' or do you want to generate the url aswell? You got that working for you?

Comment: What h ave you tried? Checksum?

Comment: i want to generate 12Rgy3 <-- this part only, other things i know..